# How to connect to WIFI Access Points?

Tags: android, wifi

I developed an application in which i scanned for all the WIFI networks and listed it in a listview. Now, i want that when user tap on this listitem it will behave same as native wifi network i.e. it will ask for password and then if password is correct ,connects to network otherwise show a message that password is incorrect.And also if it is open network it willnot ask for password.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build an AlertDialog there, and use one EditText to give the input password and set the edittext to the dialog. inside the editText.setType() method use the InputType class also...this will surely help you..
see the reference.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html